# Finding an appropriate upper bound for $\frac{x^2-4}{x-1}$ at $x=0$ and $x=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity

I am investigating the continuity of the function $\frac{x^2-4}{x-1}$ at $x=0$ and  $x=2$.

Here's a part of my proof;

> $$\lvert f(x)-f(0)\rvert =\left\lvert\frac{x^2-4}{x-1}-4\right\rvert$$
>   $$=\left\lvert \frac{x(x+4)}{x-1}\right\rvert$$
>   $$=\left\lvert \frac{x(x+4)}{x-1}\right\rvert$$
>   $$=\frac{\left\lvert x\right\rvert\left\lvert x+4\right\rvert}{\left\lvert x-1\right\rvert}$$

The challenge I have is to find an appropriate upper bound for $\frac{1}{x-1}$ at $x=0$ and $x=2$. Please, can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$\lvert f(x)-f(0)\rvert =\frac{\left\lvert x\right\rvert\left\lvert x+4\right\rvert}{\left\lvert x-1\right\rvert}$$
>
> The challenge I have is to find an appropriate upper bound for $\frac{1}{x-1}$ at $x=0$ and $x=2$. Please, can anyone help out?

You want to stay *close enough* to $x=0$ to ensure $\tfrac{1}{x-1}$ stays bounded.
You obviously don't want to go near $x=1$, since $\tfrac{1}{x-1}$ then becomes (arbitrary) large. Limit yourself to a distance of e.g. $\tfrac{1}{2}$ from $x=0$, then:
$$|x|<\tfrac{1}{2} \iff -\tfrac{1}{2} < x < \tfrac{1}{2}\iff -\tfrac{3}{2} < x-1 < -\tfrac{1}{2}$$
What does this tell you about $|x-1|$ and thus about $\tfrac{1}{|x-1|}$?

Comment: @ StackTD: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mike You're welcome!

Comment: @ StackTD: Does it mean that, $\frac{1}{|x-1|}<\left|\frac{3}{2}\right|$?

Comment: Do it in steps. From $-\tfrac{3}{2} < x-1 < -\tfrac{1}{2}$, what about $|x-1|$? And then, careful with the inequalities, what about $\frac{1}{|x-1|}$?

Comment: @  StackTD: Now, I got $\frac{1}{|x-1|}<2$.

Comment: That's right...!

Comment: @ StackTD: Thank you very much! God bless you!